# Unable to import AppDatabase.Schema into KMM Android DatabaseDriverFactory

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, sqldelight

Just trying KMM with sqldelight 2.0.0. AppDatabase is correctly generated:

[image]

However I am unable to import it into my `DatabaseDriverFactory`:
[image]`

What am I missing here? The `AppDatabase` is generated and is public - so, why can't I import it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suddenly worked after restarting Android Studio which invoked a Gradle sync. Strange thing is that I can't remember I forgot a sync or got a warning about this. Anyways, now it works.